# MLE has any competitors?

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I am learning about characteristics of statistical estimators such as Efficiency and Minimum Variance.  For example , on the topic of MLE, it says, here (1) it says that : "*MLE is popular for a number of theoretical reasons, one such reason being that MLE is asymtoptically efficient: in the limit, a maximum likelihood estimator achieves minimum possible variance* "

But it does not provide any examples as possible competing estimators. I am being facetious, but right now since I am in my apartment room by myself, I could say that I am the fastest person in my room : this statement is true, but it holds little weight because I am the ONLY person in my room. If there were 2 people in the room, I could then say : Provided I am the fastest person in this room, it means I am faster than Person 1 and Person 2.

In MLE, they never provide any examples to contextualize this fact. MLE achieves minimum possible variance, great ... but what compared to which other competitors? Compared to Bayesian Estimation? Compared to Random Guessing? Compared to a Static Constant?

Are there some tangible examples where I can see that MLE has a lower variance to some actual, well known estimator instead of just some "arbitrary phantom estimator"?

PS: I see the argument: The lowest possible variance of the parameter of any probability distribution is given by the Cramer Rao Lower Bound (CRLB). And, only the MLE can have the CRLB. Therefore, MLE has lowest possible variance amongst all estimators. But this again is like me saying: I am doing a race to see who is the fastest person in the world but I won't tell anyone the location of the race - therefore I am fastest.

Footnotes:

- (1) https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2019/11/28/asymptotic-normality-mle/

Comment: MLE definitely doesn’t have the lowest variance among all estimators. Consider an estimator $\hat\theta=4$, that is, estimating the parameter $\theta$ to be $4$ every time, no matter the data. This estimator has a variance of zero!

Comment: Similarly, the MLE is not always admissible, ie there exist other estimators doing uniformly better, check the keywork `Stein effect`  for an illustration.

Comment: My earlier comment is to say that the quoted assertion that MLEs have minimum variance is not correct. In estimating $\mu$ of $N(\mu,1)$, $\hat\mu =4$ has a variance of zero, which is the truly minimum possible variance. Perhaps reread the section of your book from which that quote comes to find the context.

Comment: This question is self-contradictory: MLE does not attempt to minimize variance.  Some other methods do; many do not.  This exposes a basic underlying issue: how does one go about comparing estimation procedures?  You need a *loss function* and the comparison is performed using the associated *risk function.*   Those are good keywords to search our site for [existing answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=estimat*+loss+risk).

Comment: Other estimation techniques migth be: Generalized Method of Moments
Generalized estimation equations
Maximum a posteriori estimation
Bayesian methods
Empirical risk minimization
Cost sensitive machine learning. However @Frank Harrel noted "MLE is so general (handling censored data, correlated data, …) and so efficient that I’m not sure if it’s time-efficient to deal with the other criteria you listed. And MLE has asymptotic efficiency among all estimators that are consistent. The main way to beat MLE is to bring in outside information into the log likelihood. Bayes does this formally..."

Comment: Also method of quantiles, method of L-moments, minimum chi-squared (quite convenient in some situations), .. etc  etc ...